# Cannot type in CKeditor with fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, ckeditor, fancybox

This is the code I used for implementing an edited version of CKeditor in my cakephp project.

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div class="umsg_div" id="umsg_div">
        <?php           
            echo $this->Form->create('Inbox',array('action'=>'private_message_reply','id' => 'form_umsg'));
        ?>

        <ul >           
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Inbox.to_id',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>@$message_details['Inbox']['from_id'],'id'=>'to_id')); ?>
            <li><div class="blue_title">Send Private Message</div></li><br/>
            <li>Subject</li>
            <li><?php echo $this->Form->input('Inbox.subject',array('type'=>'text','class'=>'subject','label'=>false));?></li><br/>
            <li>Message</li>
            <li>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Inbox.message',array('type' => 'textarea','id'=>'user_message','rows'=>"2",'style'=>'width:130%','label'=>false));?>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    if (CKEDITOR.instances['user_message']) {                   
                        CKEDITOR.instances.user_message.destroy();
                     }
                     CKEDITOR.replace( 'user_message',{
                                toolbar : 'Basic',
                    });

                </script> 
            </li>
            <li style="text-align:right;padding:10px;"><input type="submit" name="umsg" value="Send" class="normal_button"/> or <a href="#" onclick='return hide_reply();'>Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I used ckeditor in my project in many places... but in this place I can not type in textfields.

Comment: What happens when you load the page ? does the CKEDITOR get initialised ? what errors are you getting ? have you tried using a debug tool such as firebug ?

Comment: everything is sounds clear but i can not type in textarea..It seems like disabled or something

Answer (score 1):

Basically the DOM events are being overwritten so what you need to do is use a setTimeout on the afterLoad to fix the problem:

```
$("#id_of_fancybox_thingy").fancybox({

    //all your existing stuff goes here...

    afterLoad:function(){
        setTimeout(function(){

            if (CKEDITOR.instances['elementname']) {
                CKEDITOR.instances['jelementname'].destroy();
                delete CKEDITOR.instances['elementname'];
            }
            CKEDITOR.replace('elementname', { "toolbar": [ [ "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "PasteText", "PasteFromWord", "-", "Print" ], [ "Undo", "Redo", "-", "Find", "Replace", "-", "SelectAll", "RemoveFormat" ], [ "\/" ], [ "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "-", "Subscript", "Superscript" ], [ "NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "Blockquote" ], [ "JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock" ], [ "Link", "Unlink", "Anchor" ], [ "\/" ], [ "TextColor", "BGColor" ], [ "Maximize", "ShowBlocks" ] ], "height": "200", "width": "690" });

        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that Fancybox clones what you give it as its content, which means that all of the event handlers of the original DOM elements are lost. In other words, if you have an HTML `<span>` element and you've registered an event handler on it, like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#span-id').click(function(){
        alert('hello world!');
    });
});
```

and you want to show this `<span>` inside the Fancybox, then on its click, you won't get any message.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension to the previous poster who pointed out the inaccessibility of the DOM elements due to Fancybox cloning the contents:

One option may be to attach it after the Fancybox has completed:

```
$("#stuff").fancybox({
            // [Your settings]
    onComplete : function() {
                // Register your CKeditor here
                if (CKEDITOR.instances['user_message']) {                   
                    CKEDITOR.instances.user_message.destroy();
                 }
                 CKEDITOR.replace( 'user_message',{
                            toolbar : 'Basic',
                });
    }
});
```

This might be a bit hackish and, as a disclaimer, I never worked with Fancybox. But here's the API for the callbacks: http://fancybox.net/api

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using another editor now..thanks for your try bro.Will let try it for sure..

Comment: @jack Can you tell me which editor is you are using now? is that editor solved this issue?