# Unable to type in editor box of CKEditor

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

I am integrating an custom build of CKEditor in my angular project and using a trial version of it.

I am able to initialize the editor and able to show all custom toolbar items on the toolbar as well.

Issue is that I am not able to type any content in the editor, neither I am able to paste anything.

```
`<p style="text-align:justify;"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p><p style="text-align:justify;"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>`
```

i get above data in console where i can see the tags but content replaced by `&nbsp;`

and while typing i dont even get the console.

below is the implemented code:

**HTML:**

```
`<ckeditor [editor]="CkEditor" class="classic-editor" id="editorCk" [(ngModel)]="editorContent"
                (ready)="onReadyChanged($event)" >
              </ckeditor>`
```

****Typescript file:****

```
`
import * as Editor from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

onReadyChanged(event?) {
    let toolbarItems = [];   
    this.edi = document.getElementById('editorCk');
      toolbarItems = Array.from(event.ui.componentFactory.names());
      console.log('Available toolbar items: ' + toolbarItems);
      this.CkEditor.create(this.edi, {
        initialData: this.editorContent,
        isReadOnly: true,        typing: {
          autoGrow: true, // Enables automatic editor height adjustment as you type
          blockSpaces: true, // Automatically adds non-breaking spaces in certain contexts
      },
         licenseKey: 'ZUJUSmw1Rm9SdnZKd09TRitmTGZrZzUvU3pFeGZpYUgwWXd5bFZGQWtyWFNCTGlPZE54TjJ3SlRpYlRmLU1qQXlOREF6TXpFPQ==',
        toolbar: {
            items: toolbarItems 
        },
        editor: {
          data: '<p>Hello, CKEditorss!</p>',
          on: {
            change: (event) => {
              console.log('Editor content changed:', event);
            }
          }
        }
      }).then((res) => {
     
         res.disableReadOnlyMode('editorCk');
        const editorContent = res.getData() || '';
        
      const root = res.model.document.getRoot();
      console.log('root.getRoot();', root);
    
        res.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
          console.log('Editor content changed:', res.getData());
        });
        console.log('Loaded plugins:', res.plugins.list);
        console.log('Editor configuration:', res.config._config);
        console.log('Editor DOM element:', res.ui.element);
        console.log(res, 'ck editor ready'); 

      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.stack, 'error editor');
      })
  }
`
```

****package.json:****

```
`{
  "name": "MangoApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng s --o --c='dev'",
    "dev": "ng s --o --c='dev'",
    "qa": "ng s --o --c='test'",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.27",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-pagination": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "41.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "41.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.7.5",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "8.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^19.1.0",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^13.1.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^8.0.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:../../../Users/kpatb/Downloads/ckeditor5-41.1.0-onxcjnxd6cdl",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.1.6",
    "docx": "^7.4.1",
    "echarts": "^5.4.3",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "file-viewer": "^1.2.0",
    "html-docx-js-typescript": "^0.1.5",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mustache": "^4.2.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^2.1.4",
    "ngx-echarts": "8.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.7.6",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^14.3.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "windows-iana": "^5.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~14.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~14.4.0",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^2.20.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "6.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/mustache": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
`
```

Not sure why I am not able to type or paste the data in it. can someone please helps me with the editor?

I tried `res.disableReadOnlyMode('editorCk');` and passing `isReadOnly: false` which is in the document of it but its not working.

****Related question but not helpful****

[CKEditor: can't type in editor field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516820/ckeditor-cant-type-in-editor-field)

[Cannot type in CKeditor with fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293716/cannot-type-in-ckeditor-with-fancybox)

[Not able to type in ckeditor on safari or ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054945/not-able-to-type-in-ckeditor-on-safari-or-ipad)